Is there a way to impose a time limit on a chunk of R code even though a part of the code is running in C?
I have a part of a function which later runs in a loop and I want to impose a time limit on a part of this function. It should return NAs in case the time limit is exceeded to prevent my whole program from running too long. The problem is that the optimisation, a part of the code, runs in C, so withTimeout() from R.utils doesn't work.
The function I want to time-restrict is ugarchfit() from the rugarch package. The documentation indicated that the optimisation runs in C code for efficiency.
Code to be time restricted:
fit <- tryCatch(
  {
    ugarchfit(spec = spec,
              data = data,
              solver = 'hybrid')
  },
  error = function(e){
    cat('\nSolvers did not work for one observation (Index: ', index_name, ' Spec: ', spec_i, ', Dist: ', dist,'):', e$message, '\n\n')
    
    return(NA)
  }
)

I've already tried to use withTimeout() from R.utils. This didn't work because of the already mentioned problem that a part of the code runs in C and this function only works for R.
I also tried to use mcparallel() in combination with mccollect() and Sys.sleep() to circumvent the problem, but this didn't work either.

Rather than using raw time, can you restrict the number of optimisation steps - I'd imagine the routines have this
